# Correlation between 2 functions

Tags: cross-correlation, correlation

I have a periodical function $f(x)$ that is sampled in time, at a rate of 1 millisecond.

Together with this, I also have a second function $t(x)$.

I want to find the correlations between periods of the first function and the second function $t(x)$.

How can I approach this issue?

Comment: There is no such predefined thing as "correlation between periods". You can compute a correlation function for your two functions.

Comment: Do you have samples of the second function too?  Are they sampled at the same rate?  Are the functions' periods the same?

Comment: yes, I have samples of the second function, and no, they have diff periods

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei: is period of one of the functions known?

Comment: I'm new to DSP, but what about wavelet coherence (or squared coherence)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merely compare the periods of the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, you could use the following "metric" (it might not technically be one if it disobeys the triangle inequality, but someone else will have to check for that):

$\Delta (f_1, f_2) \equiv \dfrac{\left| T_1 - T_2 \right|}{\max {T_1, T_2}}$

Then the similarity can simply be defined as $s(f_1, f_2) \equiv 1-\Delta(f_1, f_2)$

Comment: What are T1 and T2?

Answer (score 0):

[Cross correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) is used for comparing functions